# Android: Video stream on RTP

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtp

I am doing one test app in android which will stream video+audio of mobile camera to RTP Server.

I got one example on internet to stream audio on RTP. But how to stream video over RTP from android?

I tried to stream video using following code but it is not working -

`Socket soc=new Socket("10.1.7.195",6789);
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());`

I found many questions on this topic, but no one got proper answer for this.

Also why android has not implemented RtpStream for video? why it is only for audio(AudioStream)?

Can I implement my own VideoStream extended by RtpStream? then what about native methods used in AudioStream?

Thanks, 
Yogesh

Comment: anyone know what i m missing here?